# programmatically migrating tests from self.assert to bare asserts

Tags: python, testing, refactoring, pytest

I have a relatively large test code base which I will migrate from nose to py.test. I would also like to take advantage of py.tests 'bare assert' functionality so that I'd need to make a lot of the following changes (for example):

```
self.assertEquals(a, b)
```

->

```
assert a == b
```

The code base is in practice too large for me to consider doing this by hand. With some git and sed magic I can get rid of about half of the self.asserts, but that still leaves me with an awful lot to do and the script is already getting somewhat complex.

It occurred to me that I'm probably not the first person to have done this. So: have any nice scripts to do this kind of thing? Or know of any nice tool that can programmatically refactor python (note: I'm aware of python-rope but to be honest at a glance that didn't seem particularly convenient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `py.convert_unittest` from the [pycmd package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycmd) for transforming the `self.assert*` alternatively.  It doesn't deal with rewriting the inheritance, though.

Not sure it makes sense but you might also checkout the related [pycmd hg repository](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pycmd) and tweak the script, possibly submitting pull requests.  If you like, i'd help factoring out the script into a new repo (also on github, if you prefer) and then advertise it so people with the same problem can start sharing efforts.  As i am not using unittest myself for a longer time (surprise!) i don't have interest to drive this effort but i am willing to help along.

Comment: Great, I'll take it for a spin and see how I get on. Cheers!

Comment: Excellent. That was a great start. Leaves me with a few leftovers though (already doing much better than my hacked up sed script though):

    git grep self\.assert | wc -l
    380

I'll look into it and if I see some easy fixes, submit PRs

Comment: actually I was running it incorrectly, but it still misses a few things (unittest2 stuff perhaps like assertTrue, assertFalse, assertNone and friends). Fixes should be trivial. PR coming up

Comment: worked a treat. Thanks again. PR sent with some small improvements